# Bash; find average for every 10 minutes in a <timestamp,value> file

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, awk

I have a file formatted as  for every second from 09:00:00 - 16:59:59, eg;

```
[...]
10:59:49,76.77
10:59:50,38.78
10:59:51,23.23
10:59:52,12
10:59:53,26.47
10:59:54,10.2
10:59:55,32.67
10:59:56,14
10:59:57,42
10:59:58,100
10:59:59,100
[...]
```

When I try and graph this the data is too clustered to make sense of, so I am looking to find averages to help it be more presentable.

How could I go about finding the average of every 10 minutes in the file, eg;

```
09:00:00 - 09:09:59
09:10:00 - 09:19:59
..
..
10:00:00 - 10:09:59
10:10:00 - 10:19:59
and so on...
```

I had planned on using awk to find the average, but struggling to find a way to extract the 10 minute clusters to run it against;

```
awk -F "," '{ sum += $2; n++ } END { if (n > 0) print sum / n; }' test_file
```

Example code if you would like to generate timestamps for testing;

```
#!/bin/bash

seq -f "%02g" 0 59 > tmp.sec
seq -f "%02g" 30 59 > tmp.firstmin

while read line
do
    cat tmp.sec | sed "s/^/09:$line:/;s/$/,$RANDOM/"
done<"tmp.firstmin"

for i in `seq 10 15`
do
    while read line
    do
        cat tmp.sec | sed "s/^/$i:$line:/;s/$/,$RANDOM/"
    done<"tmp.sec"
done
```

Comment: Is your file sorted by time? Also, it would help if you could give a more representative example so we can easily test any solutions we come up with. Your current example only has times for a single minute, so it's not helpful for testing.

Comment: Yep, sorted by time.

Comment: And we can safely assume that the first second will always be 00?

Comment: Yessir - I will attach some quick example code to the main question for generating the timestamps now.

Answer (score 1):

You could just use `:` as well as `,` as the separator and then ignore the seconds, keeping only the minute:

```
$ awk -F[:,] '{
                thisInterval = substr($2,1,1); 
                a[$1":"thisInterval"0"]+=$4; 
              } 
              END{
                    PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_asc"; 
                    for(t in a){print t,a[t]/600
              }
            }'
```

The above requires GNU awk for the `PROCINFO`, but you could always just sort it again yourself afterwards. It also assumes 600 datapoints per 10 minute period.

Comment: You can simplify your solution a little bit by this way: `awk -F[,] '{
                thisInterval = substr($1,1,4); 
                a[thisInterval"0"]+=$2; 
              }`. Just pick the first four characters from the first field. Not tested, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can match the "0:00" in the time stamp to detect the beginning of a new ten minutes period.
Here is an example in pure bash. It will only handle integer value, but since calculing the average is not your difficulty, you should be able to adapt it.

```
#!/bin/bash

SUM=0
while read line;
do
  # search for "hh:m0:00"
  if [ "${line:4:4}" = "0:00" ]
  then
    # reached new 10 minutes period
    # get average from sum and save it
    echo $((SUM/600)) >> results.txt

    # reset sum
    SUM=0
  fi

  # increment sum with this line value
  SUM=$(($SUM+${line:9}))
done < input.txt
```

Comment: This would require that there are lines generate on exactly those timestamps, which may not be the case. Also, don't parse text in shell loops.

Comment: Given is description and example, I assumed that every second timestamp would be present.

Answer (score 0):

GNU **`awk`** approach:

Sample simplified `testfile`:

```
09:00:00,1
09:03:00,3
09:09:59,6
10:00:00,1
10:02:49,76.77
10:03:50,38.78
10:05:51,23.23
10:07:52,12
10:09:53,26.47
10:09:59,10.2
10:59:55,32.67
10:59:56,14
10:59:57,42
10:59:58,100
10:59:59,100
```

---

```
awk -F',' 'BEGIN{ d = "9999 01 01 " }
          { 
              gsub(":", " ", $1); 
              if (!ts) ts = mktime(d $1);
              sum += $2; cnt += 1
          }
          cnt == 1 { next }
          (mktime(d $1) - ts) == 599 {
              print sum / cnt;
              ts = sum = cnt = 0
          }' testfile
```

The output:

```
3.33333
26.9214
```

Answer (score 0):

10 minutes = 600 seconds, so I decided just sum the second field of every 600 lines and print this value divided by 600, when each 600-th line is reached.

```
awk -F, '
NR % 600 == 1 {
    start = $1
}
NR % 600 == 0 {
    printf("%s - %s => %f\n", start, $1, avg / 600)
    avg = 0 
}
{
    avg += $2   
}
' input.txt
```

**Output**

```
09:00:00 - 09:09:59 => 49.807600
09:10:00 - 09:19:59 => 50.171900
09:20:00 - 09:29:59 => 47.775433
09:30:00 - 09:39:59 => 48.605350
09:40:00 - 09:49:59 => 49.591117
...
13:20:00 - 13:29:59 => 50.347733
13:30:00 - 13:39:59 => 50.321833
13:40:00 - 13:49:59 => 49.923333
13:50:00 - 13:59:59 => 48.644683
14:00:00 - 14:09:59 => 49.957433
...
16:00:00 - 16:09:59 => 50.333633
16:10:00 - 16:19:59 => 51.799317
16:20:00 - 16:29:59 => 50.931450
16:30:00 - 16:39:59 => 50.734167
16:40:00 - 16:49:59 => 49.857383
16:50:00 - 16:59:59 => 50.433733
```

---

To generate `input.txt`, I created two programs, use the one that you like. The second program is faster.

**First**

```
date -f <(seq -f '@%g' 21600 50399) '+%H:%M:%S' | 
awk '{
    printf("%s,%.2f\n", $0, rand() * 100)
}'
```

**Second**

```
awk '
BEGIN {
    for(i = 9; i < 17; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < 60; j++) {
            for(k = 0; k < 60; k++) {
                printf("%02d:%02d:%02d,%.2f\n", i, j, k, rand() * 100)  
            }
        }
    }
}'
```